# how do I set a custom header in a curl config file

Tags: http, curl, http-headers

How do I add the option for setting a custom header in a curl config file?
Neither of the following lines did work:

```
Header = 'x-abc: xyz'
header = 'x-abc: xyz'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`-H:"x-abc: xyz"` works fine:

```
curl -vvv -K headerfile  http://www.google.com -o /dev/null
* About to connect() to www.google.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 74.125.230.243...
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* connected
* Connected to www.google.com (74.125.230.243) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl
> Host: www.google.com
> Accept: */*
> x-abc: xyz
```

.....

Comment: I know, but that was not the question.

Comment: I meant add -H:"x-abc: xyz" in your file. In the above example I added -H:"x-abc: xyz" to the file "headerfile" and it worked.

Comment: OK, that's the solution!

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your snippet with the code: you just needed to use double quotes `"` instead of single quotes `'`.

With this change both statements work fine.

```
Header = "x-abc: xyz"
header = "x-abcd: xyz"
```