# curl --config file with multiple headers

Tags: curl

I have a curl config file that I'm calling with -k and it works fine;

```
url = "http://some-url"
header = "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8"
silent
show-error
```

The problem is I want to add a second hesder item for a specific specific SOAP action (SOAPAction: urn:....) and I can't seem to get the syntax right. I've tried this and lots of other variation!;

```
header = "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8, SOAPAction: 
urn:IProductsService/HAL_DiscountUpdate"
```

but this doesn't work. I've also tried the advice here; [how do I set a custom header in a curl config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27127195/how-do-i-set-a-custom-header-in-a-curl-config-file) and that doesn't seem to work either.

Have I missed something?

I can get;

```
curl -v -H 'SOAPAction: urn:MySOAPACTION' --config my_curl.cfg
```

to work fine but I really need it to be in the config file.

Thanks.

Comment: just add one more `header =` line for each header you want to add!

Comment: Yep, that worked, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just add one more `header =` line for each new header you want to add. To extend your config file from the question to also pass on your shoe size:

```
url = "http://some-url"
header = "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8"
header = "Shoe-size: 10"
silent
show-error
```